# Process Jobs from a list with Java Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, list

I have a program which has to process a list with many jobs. To speed up the whole things, I would like to implement Threads.

I think about something like this:

**Main-Class**

```
// I have a joblist with 100 entries
int iAmountThreads = 5;
for(Job oJob : joblist)
{
//only execute 5 Jobs at the same time
        if(Thread.activeCount() < iAmountThreads)
        {
            Runnable threadJob = new JobRunnable(oJob);
            Thread myThread = new Thread(threadJob);
            myThread.start();
        }
    }

//wait here until all jobs from the joblist are finished
```

**Runnable Class Implementing Runnable**

```
public class JobRunnable implements Runnable
{
     private Job oJob;

     public JobRunnable(Job _oJob)
     {
         oJob = _oJob;

     }

     public void run() 
     {
        //processing of the job
     }
}
```

I'm looking for a way to run 5 Jobs at the same time until the whole list is processed. When one Job is finished -> the next Thread shall start.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: have a look at the [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html)

Comment: Go for Executor Framework that is the best for such a scenerio. For more detail go to : http://www.javaworld.com/article/2078809/java-concurrency/java-101-the-next-generation-java-concurrency-without-the-pain-part-1.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a fixed thread pool, via the executor API:

```
Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

// all jobs are submitted sequentially, but only 5 jobs execute concurrently at a time
for(Runnable job : jobs)
{
    executor.execute(job);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is using Java 8 parallel streams. A simple implementation would be:

```
List<JobRunnable> tasks = ...;
tasks.parallelStream()
    forEach(JobRunnable::run);
```

This can be rearranged and you don't need to use `Runnable`; you can use any method from any class. You have to be careful for thread safety though, not to have shared state between the objects from the list.

Comment: For utilizing the Fork/Join API (parallel execution) using Java 8 stream API. +1

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5)`